# Updating to mysqli and cant get database to read

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

After a upgrade to php7.0 my site won´t read from my database.
Dont really understand what´s wrong, it worked before.
I can write to the database, so i have connection.
I know the code isn´t the nicest, but I´m learning ;)

```
        <?
    $objConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password") or die(mysqli_error());
    $objDB = mysqli_select_db($objConnect, "Utedansen");
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM anmalan where fnamn !='' ORDER BY intrade DESC, enamn, fnamn";
    $objQuery = mysqli_query($objConnect, $strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");

    $result = mysqli_query($objConnect, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM anmalan where intrade = 'Sponsorbiljett'");
    $count = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($objConnect, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total2 FROM anmalan where intrade = 'Matbiljett'");
    $count2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    $result3 = mysqli_query($objConnect, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total3 FROM anmalan where intrade = 'Eftersläpp'");
        $count3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
        ?>

        <!-- Further down --!>


    <?
        $count=0;
        while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array ($objQuery))
    {
        $count=$count+1;
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?=$count;?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["ID"];?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["BET"];?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["enamn"];?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["fnamn"];?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["telefon"];?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["email"];?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["intrade"];?></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" value="<?=$objResult["ID"];?>"></td></div>
        <td><div align="center"><a href=edit.php?id=<?=$objResult["ID"];?>>Redigera</td></div>
        <td><div align="center"><a href=betalat.php?id=<?=$objResult["ID"];?>>Betalat</td></div>
        <td><div align="center"><a href=paminnelse.php?id=<?=$objResult["ID"];?>>Påminnelse</td></div>
        <td><?=$objResult["Tiden"];?></td>
      </tr>
    <?
    }
    mysqli_close($objConnect);
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Checked your error log?

Comment: Do you have `short_open_tag` set to `on` in your php.ini? It's off as default in 7.x. (which requires you to start your php-blocks with `<?php ` instead of just `<?`).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much Magnus!